# Python Google Places API - next_page_token works once

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

**Brief:**

I'm using Google places API `googlemaps`, specifically `places` function to return places from googlemaps using a text query search.

**Problem:**

By default, the function returns 20 items. In order to query the you should query `next_page_token` to give you the next 20 items. It only works once, so I end up have 40 items maximum for my search term.

Here is a text query search for a "gas station" term that should return various results. You can see `next_page_token` appearing the first time.

```py
> places_result = gmaps.places(query = 'gas station',location='30.033333,31.233334', radius=100000, open_now=False)
> pprint.pprint(places_result)

{'html_attributions': [],
 'next_page_token': '<token-code>'
.
.
```

The second time it works as well:

```py
> places_result = gmaps.places(query = 'gas station', page_token = places_result['next_page_token'])
> pprint.pprint(places_result)

{'html_attributions': [],
 'next_page_token': '<token-code>'
```

The third time it **doesn't** work, lacking the `next_page_token`:

```py
> places_result = gmaps.places(query = 'gas station', page_token = places_result['next_page_token'])
> pprint.pprint(places_result)

{'html_attributions': [],
 'results': [{'business_status': 'OPERATIONAL'
.
.
```

The below is from google API documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging):

**Accessing Additional Results**

"By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20 establishment results per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages. If your search will return more than 20, then the search response will include an additional value — next_page_token. Pass the value of the next_page_token to the pagetoken parameter of a new search to see the next set of results. If the next_page_token is null, or is not returned, then there are no further results."

Is this by the API's design? Because the putting the search term in google maps website returns much more results that I'd like to match.

Comment: It won't ever work the third time, there will only ever be three pages (two next page tokens, 60 results, but there may be less)

Answer (score 0):

You can use time.sleep for the seach is complete. Like:

```
places_result  = gmaps.places_nearby(query = 'gas station',location='30.033333,31.233334', radius=100000, open_now=False)
time.sleep(3)
places_result  = gmaps.places_nearby(page_token = places_result['next_page_token'])
```

Comment: Why is sleeping needed? Is there no other solution than a delay? Are 3 seconds always enough?